# Where can I set TLSv1.2 for web distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

according to the official documentation (https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/aws/cloudfront-update-https-tls-v1-1v1-2-to-the-origin-addmodify-headers/) I should be able to set the TLS version by going to the "General" tab, then "edit" and then "origin ssl protocols".

However, in my WEB distribution, I can't see this section. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are editing your distribution you can find it by going to General, the clieck edit and then update them here:

[image: edit cloudfront distribution]

You can further update the protocol policy by going to Behaviours and then Edit and setting the Viewer Protocol Policy here:

[image]

Comment: but...is it only available with a custom certificate? I am using cloudfront one

Comment: Yes.  But I just realized.  Are you trying to set the general Security Policy or the security policy between CloudFront and your Origin?

Comment: General security policy...I don't want to pay a cert to aws :(

Comment: SSL Certificates from AWS are free!  Go to AWS Certificate Manager and create one in US-EAST-1 region and you'll be able to attach it to CloudFront.

Comment: Ah ok, just one thing: will my cloudfront hostname change once I change the certificate?

Comment: No, the CloudFront hostname will remain the same, but you'll now be able to use a custom domain with your CloudFront distribution. You can read how to set this up here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-alternate-domain-names.html

Comment: It asks me to set a domain name: this means that I will be forced to change my hostname...or am I doing something wrong?